# How to carry a digit when doing binary addition?

Tags: python, recursion, binary, addition

Code:

```
def add_bitwise(b1, b2):
    '''Adds two binary numbers.'''
    if b1 == '':
        return b2
    elif b2 == '':
        return b1
    else:
        sum_rest = add_bitwise(b1[:-1],b2[:-1])
        if b1[-1] == '0' and b2[-1] == '0':
            return sum_rest + '0'
        elif b1[-1] == '1' and b2[-1] == '0':
            return sum_rest + '1'
        elif b1[-1] == '0' and b2[-1] == '1':
            return sum_rest + '1'
        elif b1[-1] == '1' and b2[-1] == '1':
            return sum_rest + add_bitwise(b2[:-1],'1') + '0'
```

So I have to make this function that takes two binary numbers and adds them. This has to be done using recursion and cannot convert the numbers to decimal, add and then convert back to binary. So my base cases say that if one binary number is empty return the other and vice a versa. Then for my recursive call if two zeroes are added it returns 0 and the recursive call. If a 0 and a 1 are added it adds one and a recursive call.

Now here's where I'm stuck. Two ones makes 0 and then you have to carry a 1 to the next side but I can't figure out how to do this within the second recursive call. Sum rest is the normal recursive call, then follows the recursive call to carry the digit, and then the 0. The function must stay as designed but the recursive call needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overflow is carried over to the higher-valued digits of the result instead of just one number. The overflow recursions must sum up `'1'` against the entire `sum_rest`, not `b2[:-1]`.

Here is a slightly shorter implementation:

```
def bin_add(bin1: str, bin2: str) -> str:
    # bin1 or bin2 is empty, just use the non-empty one
    if not bin1 or not bin2:
        return bin1 + bin2   # '' + '1' or '1' + '' => '1'
    # split computation into the
    # "current/lowest digit" and "higher digits"
    head = bin_add(bin1[:-1], bin2[:-1])
    # simple case: no overflow at the current digit
    if bin1[-1] == '0':  # 0+1 or 0+0
        return head + bin2[-1]
    if bin2[-1] == '0':  # 1+0
        return head + '1'
    # overflow: add '1' to higher digits
    return bin_add(head, '1') + '0'
```

For example, consider the binaries `'011'` and `'110'`. One would do the following operations by hand:

- `0 + 1 => 1`, keep 1, no overflow
- `1 + 1 => 10`, keep 0, overflow
- `0 + 1 + 1 => 10`, keep 0, overflow
- `/ + / + 1 => 1`, keep 1, no overflow

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!